# Is a briefing considered to be a notification?

Tags: meaning

briefing

> : an act or instance of giving precise instructions or essential
>   information

notification

> : to give notice of or report the occurrence of

I am wondering if a briefing a subclass of notification, or both are completely different, or whether a briefing could sometimes be considered to be a notification and vice versa. From the definitions, it seems they are completely different.

> I wasn't briefed, but I was notified.

Comment: Is there practical reason (context) why you're asking this?

Answer (score 2):

A briefing is something more in depth. It's typically longer and consists of more details about a situation or an idea. A notification, while some details can be included, is typically short and only give the most necessary info to the recipient.